# Override author on git merge

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-merge

Is there an option like `--author` of git-commit for git-merge?

We maintain a staging environment where some changes must be performed. Some limitations make us to use only one linux user to access staging environment.

Anyway, we are a small team with cooperative initiative and we tell when doing commits, which one is the author using the --author git-commit option. However, some times we need to merge from other branches which result in a non-ff merge. This implies a commit is performed when doing this merge.

Which would be the best way to specify the author manually for the merge commit in this case?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, prevent the merge from creating the commit:

```
git merge --no-commit …
```

Then, do the commit manually:

```
git commit --author="A. U. Thor <a.u@thor.example.com>"
```

Answer (score 16):

You can `--amend` the authorship afterwards if you already did the merge. like that:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_branch
git commit --amend --author="My Nick <my.address@example.com>"
git push origin master
```

This works as desired and adds the specified author to the merge commit. No magic. :)

Comment: I feel like your answer was the most complete here, although it does imply that the --amend is necessary, when it isn't strictly.

Comment: It's not? `git merge` creates a commit and to change the author of that commit you have to `git commit --amend`.

Comment: This is not always correct, if the merge was a fast forward no commit would be created, and as so the amend would try to amend the latest commit.

Answer (score 5):

Try `git merge --no-commit ...` and then `git commit --author ...`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative could be to set the GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL environment variables:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="A. U. Thor" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="au@th.or" git merge ...
```

Comment: @Gerry Probably for the undocumented stress when the person voting realized they had to reset these variables. The inconvenience left them so behind in their work that they were unable to express their concerns. Sarcasm aside, it's probably the "destructive" nature of setting environment variables.