# Author changed after pull request is manually merged

Tags: git, github, merge, github-for-windows

Whenever I do a manual merge with git, it seems to change the author to me when I commit the manual merge of a pull request.

Here are my steps:

```
git checkout -b user1234-featurebranch master
git pull https://github.com/user1234/myrepo.git featurebranch
git mergetool #then I manually merge all changes
git checkout master
git merge user1234-featurebranch
git push origin master
```

I'm using GitHub for Windows, so at this point, I'm on the master branch, and it shows the pending (uncommitted) changes that have been merged from user1234's featurebranch.

So using GitHub for Windows, I commit the pending changes, then sync.

Then, I check GitHub, and it shows the author for all files as me.

Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Of course, I understand that any files that I had to merge locally may show me as the author, since I touched them. But all files that were auto-merged without my intervention should retain the original author, no?

**Update:** As I read more about this, it looks like pull requests should only be sent after doing a baseless merge of the upstream/forked repo. But I'm thinking there may still be cases when this isn't practical, i.e. processing multiple subsequenct pull requests involving the same code.

So still seems like there needs to be a way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override author on git merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447371/override-author-on-git-merge)

Comment: @RobinGreen Seems like there should be a way to merge without overriding the author though, no?

Comment: What do you mean by "a baseless merge of the upstream/forked repo"?